# How to check if tfjs model is loaded to browser properly

Tags: tensorflow.js

im trying to do text classification, loaded the model back to browser by

```
async function loadFile(){    const jsonUpload = document.getElementById('json-upload');    
model = await tf.loadLayersModel(tf.io.browserFiles([jsonUpload.files[0], weightsUpload.files[0]]));
model.summary();
```

have complete summary in console

```
Layer (type)                 Output shape              Param #   
    tfjs@latest:2 =================================================================
    tfjs@latest:2 embedding_Embedding1 (Embedd [null,15,50]              1009200   
    tfjs@latest:2 _________________________________________________________________
    tfjs@latest:2 conv1d_Conv1D1 (Conv1D)      [null,15,100]             15100     
    tfjs@latest:2 _________________________________________________________________
    tfjs@latest:2 max_pooling1d_MaxPooling1D1  [null,7,100]              0         
    tfjs@latest:2 _________________________________________________________________
    tfjs@latest:2 conv1d_Conv1D2 (Conv1D)      [null,7,100]              40100     
    tfjs@latest:2 _________________________________________________________________
    tfjs@latest:2 max_pooling1d_MaxPooling1D2  [null,3,100]              0         
    tfjs@latest:2 _________________________________________________________________
....
...
..
dense_Dense26 (Dense)        [null,2]                  42        
tfjs@latest:2 =================================================================
tfjs@latest:2 Total params: 1702322
tfjs@latest:2 Trainable params: 1702322
tfjs@latest:2 Non-trainable params: 0
tfjs@latest:2
```

1. is there any other way we can check if the model is loaded properly?

Answer (score 0):

`tf.loadLayersModel` will return a model only if the model is successfully loaded. Otherwise an error is thown and need to be caught. 
Using an `if` statement will fail in case the model could not be loaded.
Here is how you can check if the model is loaded successfully.

```
try {
    model = await tf.loadLayersModel(tf.io.browserFiles([jsonUpload.files[0], weightsUpload.files[0]]))
} catch(e) {
   console.log("the model could not be loaded")
}
```

Comment: Just edited, and it went without any error.. thanks.. 
_
and is there any parameters if we can check the saved model also.. that its saved properly from the browser. 
i'm saving with 
`async function saveFile(){const saveResults = await model.save('downloads://my-model-1');
   }`

Comment: It is the same thing. If `model.save` failed, an error is thrown. Using a `try catch` will tell if the model is properly saved or not

Comment: Its saving without error, loading without errror.
but prediction is constant after loading a model.

Q: getting Prediction from uploaded model is different? as i'am getting prediction from training already.

Comment: After training you need to save again the model. If not the prediction will be different

Comment: Yes, i'm Training it, then saving it.
testing results 88%acc and prediction are changing according to every unknown data. till this point all is ok.
- 
Problem is when i upload both Json and Weight files, and then try to predict, it shows the following constant result to every unknown input.  
`{Tensor
     [[0.8330757, 0.1669242],]
}`
-- 
Question: Is there any changes in "prediction function" for taking prediction from loaded model?

Comment: Can you please show more of the code in your question ? Or you can do a working snippet demonstrating the error in https://stackblitz.com

Answer (score 0):

You can use the official Tensor Flow Vis API to check if the model is loaded.

Add this to your html code:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs-vis@1.0.2/dist/tfjs-vis.umd.min.js"></script>
```

and in your js file:

```js
const model = tf.sequential();
model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: 1, inputShape: [1], useBias: true }));

tfvis.show.modelSummary({ name: 'Model Summary' }, model);
```

Open browser and you will see:

[image]